# Is there a jQuery plugin that display images (and ideally other elements) in a slideshow, that I can control manually instead of running on a timer?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Similar to [Coda Slider](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/), but instead of moving between tabs automatically based on a timer, is there any plugin where it's possible to call a method on it or something similar to move to the next item? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of jquery plugins that you might find useful.

http://www.queness.com/post/222/10-jquery-photo-gallery-and-slider-plugins

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in this:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/MovingBoxes/